# Unable to find explicit activity class, even when i declare the intent in the manifest

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, explicit-intent

I have an activity which I declare in my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
  <application>
    <activity
        android:name="com.my.InternalDummyActivity"
        android:exported="false">
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I have tried without the `exported=false` as well

The application contains an inner library with another activity.

I try to call an explicit intent from the other activity (other namespace)
But I always get an exception:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), InternalDummyActivity.class);
activity.startActivity(intent1);


ComponentName componentName2 =
    new ComponentName(
        "com.my","com.my.InternalDummyActivity");
Intent intent2 = new Intent().setComponent(componentName2); //dones work
activity.startActivity(intent2);


Process: com.comp.outter, PID: 9267
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.my/com.my.InternalDummyActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: please add the full `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: @TouhidulIslam added the manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is possible duplicate of the thread gives below
[How to call activity from a library module in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465053/how-to-call-activity-from-a-library-module-in-android-studio)

Check if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try using one of the ComponentName's [contructors](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html) that uses a Context, such as

```
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context,
"com.my.InternalDummyActivity");
```

For some reason, you can use the contructor taking two Strings only if you know the class dynamically.

Also, update your manifest as follow:

```
<activity
        android:name=".InternalDummyActivity">
</activity>
```

and application package name should be in lower case only, as mentioned in Java's Naming Conventions in [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

> Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the
>   names of classes or interfaces

Comment: I have added my code of calling the explicit intent

Comment: Try with this line in your manifest: android:name=".InternalDummyActivity">

Comment: Why do you use the ComponentName to build your Intent ? Does the new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), InternalDummyActivity.class); method work ?

Comment: yes, it does. But I don't want to be dependent on this activity. I want to check with the packageManager and then call it via string

Comment: I think the compiler needs to know which activity class you are refering to at compile time i.e. you need a dependency on InternalDummyActivity, or try passing a non final String parameter to new ComponentName()

Comment: but then what's the point in this "string","string" signature?

Comment: try using new ComponentName(context,
"com.my.InternalDummyActivity");

Comment: there is no such a signature. do you know of some? or just guessing?

Comment: There is, look at the second constructor on the doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html